# Python:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

I want to compare the value of 1800 with the values exist in the txt file. but code gave the **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''** error, i don't understand this.
code is

```
file=open("C:/Python26/freq.txt")
f2 = open("count.txt",'w')
contents=file.read();
for t in contents:
    if int(t)>1800:
        f2.write(" 0\n")
    else:
        f2.write("1 \n")
f2.close()
```

txt file contains the different frequencies which are as below

```
764
2297
3060
13098
1210
2680
2266
493
```

Comment: What is the *actual* value of `t`? Hint: it's not a parsable / valid integer value

Comment: It seems like one of your lines is empty and thus cannot be used to create an `int`. You can `print(t)` to observe what exactly is going on.

Comment: txt file contains data of frequencies of some words but every value on new line  .values are 764
2297
3060
13098
1210
2680
2266
493
129
123
59
51
462
4723
8
18309
124
21259
19858
129
230
1332
47

Comment: When you do `for t in contents`, you're iterating over single *characters* of the file, rather than iterating line by line as I suspect you intended.  Try: `for t in file: ...` instead.

Comment: It does not work because file have to read before any opration

Comment: Your first attempt to debug should be to print the value of t before trying to convert it to an int.

Comment: @ShaheenGul: Was your "It does not work" in response to my suggestion?  If so, it *does* work: you can iterate directly over an open file (e.g., using a `for` loop).  That will return you the lines of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The exception `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10` means that the value you passed to `int()` is not an integer. You read all the file as a string with `file.read()`, that's the mistake. You should read the file line by line using the loop `for t in file` and convert each line alone.

Here is my correction for the whole code:

```python
#opening files
f1 = open("C:/Python26/freq.txt")
f2 = open("count.txt",'w')

# loop through the content 
for line in f1:
    if int(line)>1800:
        f2.write("0")
    else:
        f2.write("1")

# closing files
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

I assumed that your `freq.txt` contains one number by line like this:

```
3234
23
12
78
678
33788
```

Comment: Using `.readlines()` is not necessary, since you can directly iterate over a file, line by line, as Mark Dickinson said earlier. In fact using `.readlines()` is a little wasteful here, since creates a list that holds the entire file in RAM; it's only really useful when you need to be able to randomly access the lines of a file.

Comment: @PM2Ring what about using `.readline()`, so we dont have to load the whole list.

Comment: @PM2Ring you mean `for line in f1:`?

Comment: Yes, use `for line in f1:`.

Comment: Actually, `.readlines()` _can_ be handy for situations where you need to have a list of all the lines, not just when you need random access. But generally, a program will be more efficient & use less RAM if you can simply iterate over the file line by line, like I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
file=open("C:/Python26/freq.txt")
f2 = open("count.txt",'w')
contents=file.read();
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(contents)
for t in tokens:
    if int(t)>1800:
        f2.write(" 0\n")
    else:
        f2.write("1 \n")
f2.close()
```

Comment: Probably works but including nltk is a bit like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. You could just use split.

Comment: Much too like hard work!  Just do: `file = open(...)` followed by `for t in file:`.  Get rid of the `nltk` stuff, and the `contents = file.read()`. No need to worry about newlines: the `int` constructor won't care.

Comment: bigOTHER my task was that if frequency in the list is greater than 1800 then the "0" should be save in file other wise file save "1"